# Не срабатывает Debug Pycharm Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Столкнулся вчера с проблемой, перестал работать debugger, хотя до этого все было отлично, при запуске debug какого либо файла, выходит данная строка
`C:\Python\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --save-signatures --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 58886 --file C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/Study/Stepik_v2.0/3/3.2_regular/3.2.8.py Connected to pydev debugger (build 203.5981.165)`
Хотя на совсем простых других файлах работает, и так же исполняет код данного файла без проблем
вот код:

```
import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    list_words = re.findall(r'(\b[\wA]+\b)', line)
    list_words_replased = []
    for word in list_words:
        if len(word) > 1:
            list_words_replased.append(word[1] + word[0] + word[2:])
        else:
            list_words_replased.append(word)
    x = line
    for i in range(len(list_words)):
        x = re.sub(list_words[i], list_words_replased[i], x)
    print(x.strip())`
```

Comment: А есть какая-то ошибка?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010009979-Pycharm-2020-3-Debugger-is-not-working

Comment: Нет, ошибок никаких нет, только лишь строка и ждёт какой то команды

Comment: @Jack_oS Это только Linux, а у человека Windows.

Comment: @vjeka Этот код ожидает STDIN, ты его ему предоставляешь?